# Is it possible to point a Fortran derived data type pointer to intrinsic data type?

Tags: fortran

I am working in old code where I am passed an array which has a some implied data structure in it. Is it possible to create a derived type pointer and associate it with this array? Let's assume they are all integers for now. I tried but it says data type mismatch.

Example pseudocode

```
subroutine process_array(a)
  integer,target,intent(in) :: a(*)
  ! defined elsewhere
  ! type struct
  !   integer :: b
  !   integer :: c
  !   integer :: d
  ! end type struct
  type(struct), pointer :: temp_struct(:)

  temp_struct=>a(1:size(a))
  ! do something

end subroutine process_array
```

This array "a" is passed on from various routines and is huge in size. Once I get the array instead of passing the array further down along with it's data structure (in comments) I was wondering if I could "cast" it to a derived type and pass it on as that.
The array has numerical simulation results which are fed into my modules where I slice and dice them and work on them. Making them into derived types would help my code a lot instead of dealing with offsets and keeping count of various counters. I want to avoid copying, hence was looking into pointers.

Comment: No it isn't possible, but if you explain what you want to happen we may be able to offer alternatives.

Comment: Is it a case of type-punning? Then equivalence or transfer could help. I think we need more details as @francescalus suggests.

Comment: If it was a global variable and not a dummy argument, I would use `equivalence`. Other than that you could lie to the compiler and point your pointer through a `c_ptr`. No, it is not standard conforming, but it should work in practice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Remark: The following approach uses a lot of memory for pointer variables when the target array is huge, so it may be not very nice depending on cases... Other approaches may be much better.]

Although it is not possible to point a derived type directly to an array of primitive type, how about making a derived type consisting of pointers and set them up via a function? For example...

```
module testmod
    implicit none

    type view_t
        integer, pointer :: nx, ny, vec(:)
    endtype
contains

function makeview( arr ) result( v )
    integer, target, intent(in) :: arr( : )
    type(view_t) :: v

    v % nx  => arr( 1 )
    v % ny  => arr( 2 )
    v % vec => arr( 3 : 4 )
endfunction

endmodule

program main
    use testmod
    implicit none
    integer arr( 4 * 2 ), i, offset
    type(view_t) :: v, views( 2 )

! We suppose that arr(:) consists of 2 blocks of data (each have 4 integers).

    arr(:) = [( i, i = 1, size(arr) )]  !! dummy data
    print *, "arr = ", arr

! Create a view for the first block of arr(:).

    v = makeview( arr( 1 : 4 ) )
    print *, "v % {nx, ny} = ", v % nx, v % ny
    print *, "v % vec      = ", v % vec

! Create a set of views for all the blocks of arr(:).

    do i = 1, 2
        offset = (i - 1) * 4
        views( i ) = makeview( arr( offset + 1 : offset + 4 ) )
    enddo

    arr( 7:8 ) = arr( 7:8 ) * 100   !! modify the original array

    print *, "views( 1 ) % vec = ", views( 1 ) % vec
    print *, "views( 2 ) % vec = ", views( 2 ) % vec
end
```

Result (gfortran-8 test.f90)

```
 arr =      1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8
 v % {nx, ny} =      1       2
 v % vec      =      3       4
 views( 1 ) % vec =      3       4
 views( 2 ) % vec =    700     800
```

---

Additional notes:

- We can also use `associate` to omit the declaration of a view variable (`foo`), but in this case it seems we cannot modify `foo % vec` etc (probably because it is an expression).

```
    associate( foo => makeview( arr( 1:4 ) ) )
      print *, foo % vec  !! OK
      ! foo % vec = 100   !! error
    endassociate
```

- Another approach may be to use a derived type with non-pointer components and use `c_f_pointer()`. This approach seems to work if all the components are of default primitive types (say, all default integers), but may have problem otherwise (say, a mixture of integer and double precision) due to padding (not very sure...). So, I think this approach might be useful but need much more caution ("unsafe").

```
    type altview_t
        sequence   !(not necessary for uniform integers?)
        integer :: nx, ny, vec(2)
    endtype
    type(altview_t), pointer :: altview( : )
    call c_f_pointer( c_loc( arr(1) ), altview, [ size(arr) / (sizeof(altview)/4) ] )
    print *, altview( k ) % vec
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  One issue with this approach is worst case we will have as many pointers as the array being passed in. We will have to store as many addresses as the array. I suppose there is not really anyway about it.   The biggest advantage I see is if the data structure changes there will be minimal change in the code. Thanks again, I am going to use it.

Comment: @lostInLimbo The amount of memory for pointers seems really problematic... The last approach (using c_f_pointer) and changing altview to an array pointer (type(altview_t), pointer :: altview( : )) can avoid the issue of memory amount, but it has a risk of padding etc (depending on components). I hope someone will present other approaches...